# Min width equal to child width

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a header, content, and footer element. The wrapper arround these elements is 70% of the window width. What I'm looking for is a way to set a minimum width for this wrapper. In my first fiddle it shows how it is right now: http://jsfiddle.net/fwqZX/

HTML:

```
<div class=outerWrapper>
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li class='active' id=tab1>Test1</li>
        <li id=tab2>Test2</li>
        <li id=tab3>Test3</li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <section class=content id=content>
    <div>
         sdflnsdfskdjfisahdfosad
    </div>
    </section>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS;
    color: rgba(57,58,54, 0.8);
    text-shadow: 1px 4px 6px #fff, 0 0 0 #000, 1px 4px 6px #fff;
    font-size: 150%;
}

header, nav, footer{
    -webkit-user-select: none;       
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: default;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: url('dark_wall.png'), #393A36;
}

.content, footer, nav li {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px -1px #000;
}

.outerWrapper {
    width: 70%;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 500px;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

nav li {
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    padding: 0.8em 0.5em;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    margin-right:10px;
}

nav li:not(.active) {
    box-shadow: 0 -6px 10px -7px #000, 10px 0 10px -11px #000, -10px 0 10px -11px #000, inset 1px -10px 10px -11px #444;
    background-color:#eee;
    cursor: pointer;
}

nav .active {
    box-shadow: 0 -6px 10px -7px #000, 10px 0 10px -11px #000, -10px 0 10px -11px #000;
}

.content {
    padding: 1em;
    text-align:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*transition: height 0.2s ease-in-out;*/
}

.content div {
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.content .hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}

footer {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    padding: 0.8em;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
```

In this fiddle it shows how I want it to be: http://jsfiddle.net/gkZL4/
The difference between this is only a min-width value on the .outerWrapper class.

The problem with the second fiddle, is that I have a hard coded min-width value. I would like the minimum width of the .outwrapper to adapt to the width of the navigation(the tabs).

I want to prevent using javascript for this. If it is not possible without, I will use a hard coded min-width value.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give a min-width in stead of a normal width.

Make it like this:

```
.outerWrapper {
    min-width: 70%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Also you can add an an max-width of 70% so it will never change

Comment: oh oh there is a problem with this. If the content has alot of text, the wrapper becomes very large. fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mmtcm/ Would you know a solution for this?

Comment: Like i said, if you use a max-width it should fix it.

Comment: The problem with this, is that the minimum width for the content is not the navigation anymore. http://jsfiddle.net/mLRGX/ The 'sssssssss' overflowing the box is not a problem.

Comment: I see, but why would you make such big of a text and don't use a <br /> to make the lines a bit better?

Comment: The content is very variable, and is not controlled by myself.

Comment: make the max-width 81% that should fix it. Dont ask me why but i tried 80 % and i came a little bit short so thats why i tried 81%.

Comment: I don't see what you are trying to achieve with this. To me, it is the same as max-width: 70%, but the box is a bit wider.

Comment: Could you link your fiddle? I'm not able to produce what you are trying to let me.

Comment: For such hudge contents , that never happens in real life, except for large images maybe, use max-width:xxpx;  and set overflow-x . cheers  thx for fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mLRGX/2/

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll be busy for a while now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

else, if still want it to be `width:70%;` or any size that feets content (`width:auto;/* wich is equal to not give width at all */`) + `margin:auto;`
Use display:table instead.

Using display:table will allow you not too mind how many tabs or how much content. The CSS is then , reusable within any similar structure and class names.
demo (no width/width or min-width and 3/4 tabs content wider/smaller)
http://jsfiddle.net/gkZL4/2/

```
.outerWrapper, .nowidth {
    display: table;/*or inline-block*/
    margin:auto;/* inefficient if inline-block, set text-align:center on parent */
}
.width {
    width:70%;
}
.minwidth {
    min-width:70%;
}
```

If you think `display:table` is inapropriate for old browser, you should first watch for `display:inline-block` .
IE6 applies width as min-width, IE7 will applie width given or full width. (any `display:inline-block` rules used on block-level element will need to be adapted for those two IES => haslayout with: `display:inline;` and `zoom:1;`

You may add a max-width and overflow-x:auto; to #content to avoid it to become to large on width .

Comment: I was told using tables is a bad habit. But this seems like a good place to use them to me. My target browsers are all newer than IE 8 :)

Comment: my god , these are not table when you set display:table. It doesn-t become span or whatever when you set inline-block :) HTML remains what it is. CSS makes it look like you wish..